# how to make program which rotate AM clock to PM and inverse

Tags: c#, time, rotation

i'm new with c# and i have a task to make Windows Form Application with two NumericUpDown (one for hour, one for minutes), two radio buttons AM/PM, and one button to do whole operation. If it's 23:15 and the user picked AM, when they click a button it must show message 11:15. Can you help me with the code, please?

Comment: Please redefine your questions to be a specific question. Not asking how to complete a full task.

Comment: i have two variables ''hour'' and ''minute''. how to declare them?

Comment: i tried with this but doesn't working: 

 double hour = numHour.Value ;
            double minute = numMinute.Value;

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: NumericUpDown's .Value is a decimal.  For your purposes, you probably want to either convert it to int and do some basic math, or convert it to string, parse your values into a DateTime, and use custom date/time format strings to obtain your desired results.  The latter will probably take you a little longer, but it's the more robust approach.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double hour = (double)numHour.Value ;
            double minute = (double)numMinute.Value;

            if (hour < 12 & rbPM.Checked)
            { hour = hour + 12}
            else (hour > 12 & rbAM.Checked);
            { hour = hour - 12};

            MessageBox.Show(hour.ToString() + ":" + minute.ToString());

Comment: You've got some misplaced semicolons there, and you're missing an 'if' after your 'else.'  Are you ever going to do anything with this time value other than convert it between 12/24 hour time and display it?  If so, I'd really recommend parsing it to a DateTime -- it's a little more complicated, but it will save you trouble later if you're going to end up, say, converting it between time zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed some of your syntax. I don't see anything completely wrong with your solution. Maybe the fixed syntax is all you need.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    double hour = (double)numHour.Value; 
    double minute = (double)numMinute.Value; 
    if (hour < 12 & rbPM.Checked) 
    { 
        hour = hour + 12;
    } 
    else if(hour > 12 & rbAM.Checked)
    { 
        hour = hour - 12;
    } 

    MessageBox.Show(hour.ToString() + ":" + minute.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thanks, man! now it's working :) it was a tiny stupid mistakes which i didn't saw ... again thank you, i appreciated it ;)